# Linear algebra and Hess's law?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, computational-chemistry

I am a high school student taking chemistry who was tasked to solve a large set of Hess's Law problems. Naturally I tried to find a way to get my computer to carry out this repetitive piece of work for me.

I tried to model the problem mathematically and figured out that Hess's Law problems basically had me finding the correct linear combinations.

Suppose we have a problem like this

\begin{align}
\ce{4 NH3 + 3 O2 &->6 H2O + 2N2} &\qquad &\Delta_\mathrm{r}H_1 = \pu{-1516 kJ/mol} \tag{1} \\
\ce{2 H2 + O2 &-> 2 H2O} &\qquad &\Delta_\mathrm{r}H_2 = \pu{-572 kJ/mol} \tag{2} \\
\end{align}

And our goal is to try to find the enthalpy of formation of ammonia. How would I express this as a matrix and solve it to find the linear combination. I assume we have to use the row reduce echelon method here. Just not sure how.

Comment: Searching for  [linear algebra tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=linear+algebra+tutorial) gives a lot of interesting links.

Comment: A generally useful and efficient method is the [Gauss elimination method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination), getting the triangular  matrix. Many software platforms, including Excel worksheet  functions, provide [matrix and vector operations](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/functions/matrix-category.htm) to directly solve the set of n linear equations of n variables. But for n=2, the manual substitution approach is easy.

Comment: It gets set up as the part of the Gauss' algorithm itself. You nulify the numbers below the diagonale by substrating (multiplied ) other rows.

Comment: Formulate the equation of the Hess law for each reaction and then transform it to the algebraic equation set.

Comment: Both. Coefficients for the same reaction on the same row of A. Coefficients for the same variable ( unknown Delta H ) to the same column of A. Absolute terms of f(x)=0 to the separate column b.

Comment: Maybe this video will help you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvcX1n35U5A The resulting system can be easily solved by inspection or with the help of matlab, maple. You could also make a small program to do everything.

Answer (score 24):

To convert this into a generic linear algebra problem you'd rewrite it in the form $Ax=b$ where $A$ is a matrix of stoichiometric coefficients of size $m \times n$; $x$ is a vector of length n of unknown fitting parameters (the heats you want to determine) and $b$ a known vector of length n.

For the example problem the set of equations can be written in matrix form as

$$\left[\begin{array}{rrrrr} 0 & -4 & -3 & 6 & 2\\ -2 & 0 & -1 & 2 & 0 \end{array}\right]\left[ \begin{array}{l} \Delta_\mathrm{f} H(\ce{H_2(g)})\\\Delta_\mathrm{f} H(\ce{NH_3(g)})\\\Delta_\mathrm{f} H(\ce{O_2(g)})\\\Delta_\mathrm{f} H(\ce{H_2O(l)})\\\Delta_\mathrm{f} H(\ce{N_2(g)}) \\  \end{array}\right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c } \Delta _\mathrm{r}H_1\\\Delta_\mathrm{r}H_2  \end{array}\right]$$

Since many of the terms in the vector of heats on the left-hand-side are known and equal to zero this can be rewritten as

$$\left[\begin{array}{rrlll} -4 & 6 \\ 0 & 2 \end{array}\right]\left[ \begin{array}{c } \Delta_\mathrm{f} H(\ce{NH_3(g)})\\\Delta_\mathrm{f} H(\ce{H_2O(l)})   \end{array}\right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c } \Delta_\mathrm{r} H_1\\\Delta_\mathrm{r} H_2  \end{array}\right]$$

(alternatively the original equation can be written as a $5 \times 5$ array by including additional trivial equations defining the heats of formation of the diatomic gases).

Solution of the above system should be easy, for instance in MATLAB:

```matlab
A = [-4 6; 0 2];
b = [-1516 -572]';
x = A\b
```

The problem can of course be solved by inspection. The second equation can be solved for $\Delta_\mathrm{f} H(\ce{H_2O(l)})$, which can be inserted into the first to solve for $\Delta_\mathrm{f} H(\ce{NH3(g)})$.

Comment: ```octave 5.2.0 > A = [-4 6; 0 2];  b = [-1516 -572]'; x = A\b
```

Comment: ```Python 3.8.10
 >>> import numpy as np; A = np.array([[-4, 6], [0,2]]); b = np.array([-1516, -572]); np.linalg.solve(A,b)```